# record collection variable vs record single variable

Tags: variables, record, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

What is the difference between record collection variable vs record single variable. The name suggests that one is for single and one for multiple records. However, I am confused as to why a flow would work for one particular record. It would be a waste to invest that much time on a flow for one record! Please if anyone could explain me this with an example!